# Method not Supported by Remote Object

Tags: java, rmi

I have two applications. A server app that registers the RMI object and a client app that uses the remote object. In the client I create a message class that implements serializable and sends it to the remote object but I get this error when the method is called: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object. What am I missing here?

**Client Main Method**

```java
package cryptocomclient;

import RemoteObject.CryptoComManager;
import clientUI.clientGui;
import clientUI.ClientPresenter;
import clientUI.LoginGui;
import java.rmi.*;

public class CryptoCom {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Gets the remote object reference from RemoteObjectConnection
        RemoteObjectConnection netConn = new RemoteObjectConnection();
        CryptoComManager ccm = netConn.getCCM();

        // Passes the remote object into the client for use
        CryptoComClient client = new CryptoComClient(ccm);

        LoginGui loginGui = new LoginGui();
        loginGui.setVisible(true);
        clientGui clientGui = new clientGui();


        ClientPresenter presenter = new ClientPresenter(client, clientGui, loginGui);
        clientGui.setPresenter(presenter);
        loginGui.setPresenter(presenter);
        System.out.println("All systems good to go!");
    }

}
```

**Connection That Gets Remote Object Reference**

```java
package cryptocomclient;

import RemoteObject.CryptoComManager;
import java.rmi.Naming;

public class RemoteObjectConnection {

    CryptoComManager ccm;

    RemoteObjectConnection() {
        pullFromRegistry();
    }

    // Will be used to pass the ccm to the client during dependancy injections
    // in the main method of the client app.
    public CryptoComManager getCCM() {return ccm;}

    // Looks up the name of the object in the registry and sets it's reference
    // to the ccm located here.
    private void pullFromRegistry() {
        try {
            ccm = (CryptoComManager)Naming.lookup(CryptoComManager.LOOKUPNAME);
            System.out.println("Remote object pulled from registry.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("CrytpoComCilent: CryptoComManager exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

**Client**

```java
package cryptocomclient;

import RemoteObject.CryptoComManager;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CryptoComClient {

    private ArrayList<Message> receivedMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String userName;
    private CryptoComManager ccm;

    // Constructor that takes in a reference to the remote object.
    public CryptoComClient(CryptoComManager ccm) {
        this.ccm = ccm;
    }
    //Constructor that takes no remote object reference (for testing)
    public CryptoComClient(){

    }

    // Creates a new instance of Message and returns it.
    public Message createNewMessage(String memo, String sender, String recipient) {
        //Encryption should be done here


        return new Message(memo, sender, recipient);

    }

    // Returns a message from the recived arrayList at the specified index.
    public Message openMessage(int index) {

        if (receivedMessageList.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return receivedMessageList.get(index);

    }

    // Takes in a message and sends the message to the remote object
    public void sendMessage(Message message) throws RemoteException {

        ccm.sendMessageToServer(message);

    }


    // Calls the remote object to get the stored messages then adds them to the
    // clients receivedMessageList
    public void getReceivedMessages() throws RemoteException {

        ArrayList<Message> receivedList = ccm.receiveMessagesFromServer(userName);

        for(Message message: receivedList) {
            receivedMessageList.add(message);
        }

    }

    // Removes a message from the received message arrayList
    public void removeReceivedMessage(Message message) {

        receivedMessageList.remove(message);

    }



    // Getters and setters for fields listed at the top
    public ArrayList<Message> getRecievedMessageList() {return receivedMessageList;}
    public void setReceivedMessageList(ArrayList<Message> recievedMessageList) {this.receivedMessageList = recievedMessageList;} 

    public String getUserName() {return userName;}
    public void setUserName(String userName) {this.userName = userName;}

    public CryptoComManager getCCM() {return ccm;}
    public void setCCM(CryptoComManager ccm) {this.ccm = ccm;}

}
```

**Remote Object Interface**

```java
package RemoteObject;

import cryptocomclient.Message;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface CryptoComManager extends Remote{

    public final static String LOOKUPNAME = "CryptoComManager";
    public void sendMessageToServer(Message message) throws RemoteException;
    public ArrayList<Message> receiveMessagesFromServer(String userName) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Remote Object Implementation**

```java
package RemoteObject;

import cryptocomclient.Message;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CryptoComManagerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements CryptoComManager{

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Message>> messageMap = new HashMap<>();

    public CryptoComManagerImpl() throws RemoteException{
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendMessageToServer(Message message) throws RemoteException {

        // Checks to see if the recipient already has an arraylist
        // If it doesn't creates a new arraylist with the recipient as the key
        if(!messageMap.containsKey(message.getRecipient())){
            messageMap.put(message.getRecipient(), new ArrayList<Message>());
        }

        // Gets the recipients Arraylist and adds the new message
        ArrayList<Message> recipientArrayList = messageMap.get(message.getRecipient());
        recipientArrayList.add(message);
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Message> receiveMessagesFromServer(String userName) throws RemoteException {

        ArrayList<Message> arrayListToSendBack = messageMap.get(userName);
        messageMap.remove(arrayListToSendBack);
        return arrayListToSendBack;

    }

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<Message>> getHashMap() {return messageMap;}




}
```

**Message class**

```java
package cryptocomclient;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Message implements Serializable{

    String memo,
           sender,
           recipient;

    public Message(String memo, String sender, String recipient) {
        this.memo = memo;
        this.sender = sender;
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o == this) {return true;}

        if(!(o instanceof Message)) {return false;}

        Message otherMessage = (Message)o;

        if(this.memo == otherMessage.memo &&
           this.sender == otherMessage.sender &&
           this.recipient == otherMessage.recipient) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.memo);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.sender);
        hash = 41 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.recipient);
        return hash;
    }

    public String getMemo() {return memo;}
    public void setMemo(String memo) {this.memo = memo;}

    public String getSender() {return sender;}
    public void setSender(String sender) {this.sender = sender;}

    public String getRecipient() {return recipient;}
    public void setRecipent(String recipient) {this.recipient = recipient;}

}
```

**Server App**

```java
package cryptocomserver;

import java.rmi.*;
import RemoteObject.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;

public class CryptoComServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        System.out.println("CryptoComServer starting...");

        System.out.println("Creating Registry...");

        // Creates and exports a Registry instance on the local host that
        // accepts request on port 1099
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        System.out.println("Registry created.");

        //System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        //System.out.println("Security Manager installed, Setting up service");

        try {
            // Creates instance of CryptoComManagerImpl object
            CryptoComManagerImpl ccm = new CryptoComManagerImpl();

            System.out.println("Publishing CryptoComServer...");

            // Binds the object to the registry using the LOOKUPNAME
            Naming.rebind(CryptoComManager.LOOKUPNAME, ccm);

            System.out.println("CryptoComServer ready.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);

        }

    }

}
```

**Stack**

```
run:
Oct 20, 2019 12:07:32 AM clientUI.clientGui sendButtonActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:389)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:283)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:260)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.sendMessageToServer(Unknown Source)
    at cryptocomclient.CryptoComClient.sendMessage(CryptoComClient.java:45)
    at clientUI.ClientPresenter.send(ClientPresenter.java:42)
    at clientUI.clientGui.sendButtonActionPerformed(clientGui.java:258)
    at clientUI.clientGui.access$000(clientGui.java:19)
    at clientUI.clientGui$2.actionPerformed(clientGui.java:159)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2238)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2296)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4897)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4475)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2282)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unrecognized method hash: method not supported by remote object
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:327)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:835)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I looked at that one and it looked like he didn't implement the methods from his interface correctly. I don't believe I have that problem.

Comment: Provide CryptoComClient.java and all other related files too please.

Comment: Okay, I've edit the post.

Comment: In the error message provided above, error/exception seems to have originated from `CryptoComClient.java:45` which contains `ccm.sendMessageToServer(message);`. With the code provided (removing few broken references to GUI classes), I ran `CryptoComServer.java` and then `CryptoCom`. I added `client.sendMessage(new Message("memo", "Sender", "Recepient"));` in hopes to recreate error with no luck. Code compiled and ran cleanly with no error or exception. Provide more information or code to help recreate same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Message.java class was in both the Server and Client applications but not packaged in the exact same file strcture. I refactored the structure so the Message, RemoteObjectManager, and RemoteObjectManagerImpl were all in the same package and the packages were named the same in their respective applications and everything works properly now.